# Newsletter sign up form on WordPress with GDPR plugin

Tags: wordpress, forms, gdpr, newsletter

I've read the following before posting this:

- [Newsletter sign up form on wordpress](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/31710/newsletter-sign-up-form-on-wordpress)
- [How do I expose CiviCRM forms in WordPress?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/10010/how-do-i-expose-civicrm-forms-in-wordpress)
- https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/integration/wordpress/forms/

but I'm still unclear on how we produce exactly we what we want as we are also using the Veda GDPR plugin to track opt ins.

We are planning to add a module to our custom page template asking for email addresses. An example of this page is this - https://vitiligosociety.org/what-causes-vitiligo/ (module will just before the footer)

The custom module we are having designed looks similar to this:
[image]

The only difference is the call to action will be to add an email address rather than be redirected to the membership sign up page.

What's the correct way to add the civi forms to this module and also expose the appropriate settings from the Veda GDPR plugin.

Any suggestions much appreciated! Thanks.

PS - We are using the Guttenberg editor.

Answer (score 2):

I just submitted a PR to the GDPR extension which provides a new shortcode to display the GDPR preferences on a page, see https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.gdpr/pull/217

That's what we use for providing users with an option of viewing and updating their preferences.

For all other CiviCRM form-related integration on WordPress, we use https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf-civicrm/

Comment: Thanks Justin. So if I understand correctly, you are using the GDPR plugin for newsletter sign-ups but using Caldera Forms for everything else?

We are planning to add member self service area ('My Profile' type of area) and we were wondering whether we'd use native civi exposed forms but do you think Caldera will work better for this?

Comment: Just use Caldera Forms for everything. You only need the GDPR extension if you need compliance. This saves time and effort trying to wrangle native CiviCRM Profiles which generally only do part of the job anyway. Caldera Forms integration for the win!  